# Create an "app connection"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I writing an article about how to do something like web part connection with the app model of SharePoint 2013.

Have you an architecture model to do that?
Does a standard exist to do that?

My ideas is using a JavaScript Module shared content (client side) or by SignalR.

Comment: Looking forward to the article!

Answer (score 1):

I came across this a while ago, it might be what you are looking for...even comes with a nice video!!

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2014/05/07/connected-sharepoint-app-part.aspx